# Insert data into database without using form

Tags: php, mysql

Do i insert the current directory files name into the database in PHP but without using the form??..
Because in my project a device send the pdf files on server's folder and i want to save these files name in database

Comment: Kind of background process like a cronjob possibly that reads the folder content and writes it into the database. Otherwise it's a bit unclear what you are asking exactly and coding help is of topic on Programmers.SE

Comment: Do you mean POST data to the server without using an html `<form>`? AJAX is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: thanx.now my problem is solve .I directly send the file on the server and save the file name into the database.so,no need for additional work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Of course you can.

Try:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //returns the current URL
$parts = explode('/',$url);
print_r($parts);
EDIT:

$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //returns the current URL
$parts = explode('/',$url);
$dir = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts) - 1; $i++) {
 $dir .= $parts[$i] . "/";
}
echo $dir;
```

This should return localhost/do/and save url via sql connection.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
// Perform queries 
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO urls (`url`) 
VALUES ('".$dir."')");
mysqli_close($con);
```